# How to make a rolling window of 10 records in Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a set of records that have a sequential IDs. The set of records is sorted by the ID field. I would like to take a rolling window of 10 records (i.e. records 0-9, then records 1-10, records 2-11, etc...). In Python and Pandas the following works perfectly:

```
windows = my_data_frame.rolling(10).sum().dropna()
```

I would like to accomplish the same thing in Apache Beam. Reading the [Apache Beam Programming Guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing) it appears the only way to do windowing is by timestamp. Furthermore, [this example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/d314339ed2f8d5ce385c7b40705ef13f6ea43b45/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/WindowedWordCount.java) implies that in order to accomplish windowing by record I would need to add an arbitrary timestamp to each record and then window on that timestamp.

I am very new to Apache Beam, and since windowing by record is essentially one line in Pandas, I feel that I am missing something in Beam that would allow me to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject your sequential IDs as event timestamps and use `SlidingWindow.of(10).every(1)`. The time unit depends on how you transform sequential IDs into event timestamps.

The code would look like

```
TextIO
   .read(...)
   .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, Long>() {
      @ProcessElement
      public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        c.outputWithTimestamp(..., timestamp transformed from sequential IDs)
      }
   }))
   .apply(SlidingWindow.of(10).every(1))
   .apply(Sums.longsGlobally())
```

Comment: This confirms my suspicion that this is the only way to accomplish what I want. If using Google's PubSub with Dataflow it is important to note that Dataflow will, by default, not allow these arbitrary timestamps to be too far removed from the message timestamp given by PubSub.

Comment: I was assuming the pipeline is in batch mode since you're using pandas? In that case, I don't think you need PubSub. You can just read from a batch source and inject timestamp as you wish with `outputWithTimestamp` API.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the set of records, you can write a batch pipeline. For each record, you can map it to a key/value pair, where the key is, say id/10, and the value is the record. Then you can perform a GroupByKey, which group (or in your word, window) 10 records into one key.

In your example, if you want to sum every 10 elements, you can also use the Sum transform (after you attach each record with a key), example from https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/0.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Sum.html:

```
PCollection<KV<String, Integer>> input = ...;
PCollection<KV<String, Integer>> sumPerKey = input
    .apply(Sum.<String>integersPerKey());
```

Comment: This would group records together, however, I do not believe that is the same thing as a sliding (aka rolling) window.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, what you are describing is the same as a fixed window, correct?